# Get SQLState from SQLException exception

Tags: java, exception, jdbc, runtimeexception, sqlexception

I have code which throws SQLException wrapped in RuntimeException, like as:

```
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
        Throwable t = e.getCause();
        
while ((t != null) && !(t instanceof java.sql.SQLException)) {
t = t.getCause();
}
 . . . Someother code
if (SQLState==) {
//throw new custom exception based on  SQLState);
}
```

How can I get SQLState inside if loop ? Somehow outside while loop t is null.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer

```
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        Throwable t = e.getCause();
        SQLException exp;
        while ((t != null) && !(t instanceof SQLException)) {
            t = t.getCause();
            exp= (SQLException) t;  
        }
        if (exp.getSQLState=="....")) {
             throw new custom exception based on  SQLState); 
        }
    }
```